# Create timestamp YAML log file

Tags: yaml

I'm trying to create a log file everytime my program is initiated. I managed to have it log to a static file (mylogs.log), but I would like it to create a new file when it loads up and append to that.

```
logging:
  disable_existing_loggers: false
  formatters:
    simple:
      format: '%(asctime)s - {{login}} - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
  handlers:
    file_handler:
      class: logging.FileHandler
      level: INFO
      formatter: simple
      filename: /home/pi/myprogram/logs/mylogs.log
      encoding: utf8

  loggers:
    MyProgram:
      handlers:
      - file_handler
      level: INFO
      propagate: 'no'
    Persistence:
      handlers:
      - file_handler
      level: INFO
      propagate: 'no'
  root:
    level: INFO
  version: 1
```

This (filename: /home/pi/myprogram/logs/mylogs.log) works fine, but I would like it to create a new log file. For example: 2019-08-06-22:59:59_mylogs.log. When the program is restarted, it will create a new file with the current timestamp. For example: 2019-08-07-01:01:00_mylogs.log.

Answer (score 0):

the config below will allow you to have a new file everyday with the following format:**logger_server.log.2020-03-17**. Based on that you can see where to change to get your desired output.

```
   logging:
pattern-formatters:
  LOG_FORMATTER:
    pattern: "CUSTOM LOG FORMAT %p [%c] %s%e%n"
periodic-rotating-file-handlers:
  FILE:
    file:
      path: logger_server.log
    suffix: .yyyy-MM-dd
    named-formatter: LOG_FORMATTER
root-logger:
  handlers:
  - CONSOLE
  - FILE
```

[sample code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mVTFH.png)